# Proving the analyticity of a function of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)\in H(\Omega) $  and $|f(z)|<1$ for $ z\in \Omega$ .Show that $ g(z)\in H(\Omega)$ ,where 
$$ g(z ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \{f(z)\}^n.$$

$g(z)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n .w^n $ where $w=f(z)$

$g(z)= \frac{d}{dw}\sum_{n=1}^\infty  w^{n+1} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty w^n $

$g(z)=   \frac{d}{dw}\{ w^2/(1-w)\} -w/(1-w) $

$g(z)= 1/(1-w)$

$g(z)= 1/(1-f(z)) $

Since $f(z) \in H(\Omega) $ and $|f(z)|<1$

Hence $g(z) \in H(\Omega)$

Can anyone confirm validity of this?

Comment: What is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot w^n\,?$$

Comment: Your series with the derivatives is wrong. $$\frac{d}{dz} \left[f(z)\right]^{n+1} = (n+1)\left[f(z)\right]^n\cdot f'(z).$$

Comment: Oh I see my mistake ,thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the neighborhood. If the function f(z) is analytic in a neighborhood of z0 and f(z) is analytic at z0, then f(z) is analytic at z0. If it is analytic everywhere then it is an entire function. You can check by neighborhoods or also by derivative rules. Try these out.